# SSL certificate usage in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, ssl, db2, azure-data-factory

I want to use a SSL certificate while creating a linked service in azure data factory to DB2 database. While we do it using JDBC we don't provide password for DB and only set SSL properties.
How can we do that in azure data factory? Password seems to a mandatory field there.

Comment: yes, the password is mandatory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-db2#linked-service-properties), I don't think this is possible using ADF. if you want to secure your password, you can use key-vault.

Comment: I am not taking about securing password. I want to connect to DB2 using a SSL certificate not via username/password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you said, when Data Factory connect to DB2, we must provide the password:

[image]

Even we can connect the DB2 with connection string with the  SSL certificate, we still need the password:

[image]

That means that Data Factory doesn't support using SSL certificate to connect to DB2 without the username and password.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Even i saw that on azure documentation. I was wondering if there was a way to connect using SSL properties and not username/password

Comment: @SandeepKumar Yes, I know you meaning. For this question, I would suggest you to ask [Azure support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) or post in the [Data Factory feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory), that's more about the feature support issue.

Comment: Hi @SandeepKumar, did you get any other message from Azure support now?  If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.