# How to connect to DB2 database with SSL enabled in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: db2, ssl-certificate, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I have an on-prem machine for DB2 connectivity to ADF where SHIR is installed, and I have been provided with the certificate zip file.
How to use SSL certificate for linked service of DB2 in data factory and how to get that certificate common name for linked service.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aak7.png)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-db2?tabs=data-factory#create-a-linked-service-to-db2-using-ui - following this but nothing in detail has been shared on how to setup SSL for source machine.

Comment: Is these similar threads [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61745417) helped you? by Leon Yue

Comment: Please edit your question to specify whether the target Db2-on-premises server is running on Z/OS, or  linux/unix , or  i series.

Comment: It's a windows server where SHIR is installed and registered to ADF. I just need to know how to setup SSL certification on the machine and what is certificate common name ? @mao

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The procedures below must be followed in order to utilise an SSL certificate for a DB2 connected service in Azure Data Factory:

You should extract the.pem file from the given certificate file by unzipping it.

Go to the "Author & Monitor" area of the Azure Data Factory, and then click the "Author" button.

Click the "Author & Monitor" button on the left-hand menu.

Click the "Linked services" button in the "Author" section before selecting "New."

As the type of connected service you wish to build, select "DB21."

[image]

Fill out the appropriate data on the "New Linked Service" form, including the server name, port number, and username/password.

[image]

Select the "Certificate" button after selecting the "Enable SSL" checkbox in the "Advanced" section.

[image]

Click the "Add" button in the "Certificate" dialogue box and then navigate to the location of the.pem file that you retrieved in step 1 before clicking.

[image]
The Common Name (CN) of the certificate will be automatically filled in once you've chosen the file.

[image]

To build the associated service, click "Finish" after clicking "OK" to exit the dialogue box.

[image]

The SSL certificate should now work with your Azure Data Factory linked service to connect to your DB2 source machine.